# jQuery Expand a tag not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have been trying to get the Expand Collapse on an anchor tag work but somehow I'm missing something. I went through almost all links here but wasn't finding the difference between my code and the help options.

All I want is a simple expand on click of the "+" sign for any row. I am building the div on the fly in my javascript file. Somehow I can only Expand all alternate rows. So if my response has 5 elements, I can only expand every other row! Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks,

Mayuri

```
function DisplayResultsGrid(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(index, item) {
        $("#divRequestDetails").append('<div class="requestDetailItem"><a href="#" class="lnkRequest"> + </a><div class="toggleDays">This is the text to expand</div></div>').append('<div class="rowSeparator"></div');
        $('.toggleDays').hide();
        $('.lnkRequest').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.toggleDays').toggle();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: can u please add a jsfiddle

Comment: learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending a click to ALL .lnkRequest elements every single time you are looping. You are not adding event to the current one. So first one will have first click event, plus the next one, plus the third one, etc.

You need to assign the events outside of the each loop or use event delegation.

```
function DisplayResultsGrid(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(index, item) {
        $("#divRequestDetails").append('<div class="requestDetailItem"><a href="#" class="lnkRequest"> + </a><div class="toggleDays">This is the text to expand</div></div>').append('<div class="rowSeparator"></div');
    });
    $('.toggleDays').hide();
    $('.lnkRequest').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.toggleDays').toggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: That worked Epascarello!!! Thanks a lot. I had the event outside my each loop but accidently while un-doing my changes, I added it back. Thanks once again...